# how to create a text file in asp.net MVC3 using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I just wanna ask how to generate or create textfile, becuase i want to display my data in the database as text.

im using c# in asp.net MVC 3

thank you very much! any answer will be apreciated.

Comment: Do you want to RETURN a text file to the user, or do you want to STORE a text file in a folder on the server? I don't understand "display my data in the database as text"

Comment: i just simply want to generate a textfile. like example after generating it , it will be put in the desktop or somewhere, i just want to generate a textfile with my database information in it

thanks !

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to return some data from the database in a text file that will be downloaded to user's local computer, create an **Action** in your **Controller** like in this sample:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;      

public class SomeController {

    // this action will create text file 'your_file_name.txt' with data from
    // string variable 'string_with_your_data', which will be downloaded by
    // your browser
    public FileStreamResult CreateFile() {
        //todo: add some data from your database into that string:
        var string_with_your_data = "";

        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string_with_your_data);
        var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        return File(stream, "text/plain", "your_file_name.txt");   
    }

}
```

then you can create an **ActionLink** to that action on your **View** which will trigger file download:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download Text File", "CreateFile", "SomeController ")
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can return plain text from an action by assembling a string and returning `Content(textString, "text/plain")`.

Comment: a sample code will do please, im newbie, should i make a new class in the MODEL and put the codes there, and call it from the controller or what?

Comment: Because im thinking about getting the information from my database using repository then passing it to a string variable, so after passing it to a string variable i want to generate it as a textfile.

Comment: @sgolek: Create an action method in the controller that builds a string (you can use a `StringBuilder` in a loop), then write `return Content(textString, "text/plain");`.

Comment: Thanks SLaks !, i will create an action method now and post it in a minute so you can help me more, 

BTW. what should i put int the "text/plain" ?

really noob here,

really appreciate your help ! thanks a lot

Comment: `"text/plain"` is a [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type).  You should leave it as-is, or use `"text/csv"`.